# VBA runtime error 1004 with offset

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, offset

I have a workbook containing a list of all invoices from all branches, let's call it "Everything", and basically I need to search if the invoices are found in another file containing each branch's invoices,. It's actually on file for each branch, and each file is divided with sheets by month, and I need to check in every sheet and then insert a value in a cell. Let's call this one "0001" and so on for each branch.

The "everything" file contains basically one column with the branch number, one with the invoice number, one with the issuer code and one saying if it was found on the branches files. The branches files contains the same except the branch number, and the last column says if the invoice is on the "Everything" file or not. There are cases where an invoice is on the branch file and is not on the "everything file" and also cases where it is on the everything file and is not on the branches file.

The part of the code for adding an yes or no is ok, but after finding the invoice number on the branches file I need to check if its issuer is the same as the one on the Everything file, and I am getting run-time error 1004. Can you help me? here is a sample from the code:

```
Dim cnpj as range
Dim NFE as range

Set NFE = sh.Columns(colSrch).Find(valorprocurado, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
If Not NFE Is Nothing And Range(NFE).Offset(, 8) = cnpj Then
```

The error is coming on the last line of the code. At the beginning of it I set cnpj using the Everything file, and it seems to be working. What is wrong?

Comment: If NFE is nothing it will throw an error.  VBA tests both parts of the IF statement regardless of the outcome of the other.  Try nesting another if statement for the second part.  {if not NFE is Nothing then IF range(NFE).offset(,8) = cpnj then}

Comment: @ScottCraner IT WORKED!!!!!!

Comment: Since it worked, please mark it as Answered

Answer (score 0):

I think you could write the last line as

If Not NFE Is Nothing And NFE.Offset(, 8) = cnpj Then

Answer (score 0):

As Scott suggested, I did a second if statement nested inside the first one, and it worked. Thank you very much for your help!

The code stayed like this:

```
Dim cnpj as range
Dim NFE as range

Set NFE = sh.Columns(colSrch).Find(valorprocurado, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
If Not NFE Is Nothing
if Range(NFE).Offset(, 8) = cnpj Then
blablabla
end if
end for
end if
```